# ERROR - com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When I look into the console log of my GAE/J application I see this:

```
[ERROR] Aug 09, 2013 2:48:11 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
[ERROR] INFO: Successfully processed C:\projects\myproject\myproject-stack\web\target\web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
[ERROR] Aug 09, 2013 2:48:11 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
[ERROR] INFO: Successfully processed C:\projects\myproject\myproject-stack\web\target\web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/web.xml
[ERROR] Aug 09, 2013 2:48:11 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
[ERROR] INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\projects\myproject\myproject-stack\web\target\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.0\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties' from 'C:\projects\myproject\myproject-stack\web\target\web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
[ERROR] Aug 09, 2013 2:48:11 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
[ERROR] INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
[ERROR] Aug 09, 2013 6:48:11 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader checkWorkingDirectory
[ERROR] WARNING: Your working directory, (C:\projects\myproject\myproject-stack\web) is not equal to your 
[ERROR] web application root (C:\projects\myproject\myproject-stack\web\target\web-1.0-SNAPSHOT)
[ERROR] You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.
```

What does it mean, and how do I fix it? Would this affect when I put the app online?

Comment: You might want to fix your working directory warning and then try again. I have never noticed `[ERROR]` texts like these when starting my dev app server.

Comment: "working directory warning" ?

Comment: `WARNING: Your working directory, (C:\projects\myproject\myproject-stack\web) is not equal to your web application root (C:\projects\myproject\myproject-stack\web\target\web-1.0-SNAPSHOT) You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.`

Comment: The java modules sample app has these same, but they are warnings. Anyone know why?